# memcpy slow when called in thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, memcpy

I have a problem with memcpy which I do not seem to understand. I use memcpy on a thread and it is 3-4 times slower compared to the time I get when I run it from the main. In both cases, I have 2 threads running one just waiting and one calling memcpy. Can you give me any possible explanation for this? I use a 4-core Intel machine with hyperthreading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <algorithm>
#define MILLION 1000000

#define START_TIMER(timer) {          \
  gettimeofday(&(timer), NULL);           \
}

#define STOP_TIMER(timer) {         \
  gettimeofday(&(timer), NULL);         \
}

#define TIME_DIFF(timer1, timer2, total) {      \
  long long sec_diff = 0;         \
  long long usec_diff = 0;          \
  sec_diff = (timer2).tv_sec - (timer1).tv_sec;     \
  usec_diff = (timer2).tv_usec - (timer1).tv_usec;    \
  (total)+= (sec_diff * MILLION) + usec_diff;      \
}
void copy(){
    struct timeval start, stop;
    long long total=0;
    char buff[1024*1024];
    for(int i =0;i<100;i++){

    char* temp = new char[1024*1024];
    START_TIMER(start);
    std::copy(buff,buff+1024*1024,temp);
    STOP_TIMER(stop);
    TIME_DIFF(start,stop,total);
    delete temp;
    }
    printf("%lld\n",total/100 );
}
void* mem(void* args){
    copy();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * nothing(void *args){
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
pthread_t thread;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(atoi(argv[1])==0){
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,nothing,NULL);
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
        copy();
    }
    else{

        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,mem,NULL);
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time. I hope it's not too stupid.

Comment: What happens if you initialize `buff` before your `i` loop?

Comment: Please share the code where you call the copy function from main, and from the threads. So that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens if you move the copy() in main() above the thread create, ie run the main thread copy first?

Comment: Sush The copy function is there just above the main. 
@ThingyWotsit Only one thread will execute copies. You chose which one as execution argument. 0 for the main thread, other for the created thread

Answer (score 0):

At first I could not get your code to run, when it the call to `copy()` happens the thread (passing 1 as argument).  `pthread_create` allocates a small stack size, and declaring the 1MB array `buff` was causing a segmentation fault.

I altered the code to allocate a larger stack for the thread:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    if(atoi(argv[1])==0){
        pthread_create(&thread,NULL,nothing,NULL);
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
        copy();
    }
    else{
        pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
        pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr , 20*1024*1024);
        pthread_create(&thread, &thread_attr,mem,NULL);
        pthread_join(thread,NULL);
    }
}
```

This works, and there is no difference in runtimes between copying on either thread on my machine.

However, your OS may be causing heap contention.  Every time it needs to allocate memory, it needs to gain control of a 'mutex' (of some sort, probably a spin_lock) to ensure no other thread is allocating/freeing from the heap.  This would cause the delays you are experiencing.

Comment: The code works for me as it was and I get about 100 usecs vs 300+ usecs. I tried your code too but I still have the same issue. Thanks for your time , I appreciate it. I just saw your edit about the OS and the mutex on the heap. Shouldn't this create problems for both cases? Why would it only be so obvious on one of them

Comment: Did you read my update about heap contention? I think our architectures are handling the heaps differently.

Comment: (I'm running on an I7 with 4 cores and hyperthreading, OS is Mac OS 10.11 btw)

Comment: There is no heap contention in this case - there is single thread which does the allocations. @Pol try to fill `buff` with some data before the loop; maybe additional delay is caused by `buff` being allocated into physical memory.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin can you replicate this? If the time difference was caused by physical allocation, how would this differ between threads?

Comment: @PaulBentley just spitballing here but main thread might have more memory preallocated for the stack than pthreads. I tried to replicate and it feels like copy on thread works slower but the difference is almost negligible. Nothing like 3 times difference. I just realized there is one other possibility - memory manager might do some initialization during first memory allocation for each given thread.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin My OS won't reallocate the stack when it fills up, it just crashes.  However Pol's might reallocate on segmentation fault, maybe? Your second hypothesis can be tested with running the test in the thread 10 times - only the first one iteration should be slower.  Pol - can you test this?

Comment: Thank you all! I tried filling the buff before copying and indeed it makes a difference for both cases (it reduces the time for both copy in the thread and in main). But still, the time is 3x. For running the test 10 times you mean to put the for loop into another loop of 10 iterations? Thank you

Comment: You mean that after filling the buffer, there is still a time difference between the two threads? Yes, I recommend iterating across your loop 10 times, timing each iteration individually.  This will rule out any thread initialisation start up delays.

Comment: Yes, the time difference remains the same, just lower absolute values for both cases. I also tried iterating 10 times for each case. No luck still the time improves for both cases, however, the difference is still the same

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference in the number of threads for the process when 'copy' function is called. When it is called from the main thread the 'nothing' thread already exited, so effectively there is only one thread for the process. But while it is called from the 'mem' thread there are effectively two threads in the system. This can make a difference if the system is loaded or there is contention among the threads of the process. This time difference may not exist if it is run on another machine or on less loaded machine.This theory can be verified by changing the code such that you wait in the nothing thread and cancel it only after the copy function is called.

Comment: You are right, the copy shall be before the join. I fixed this but I still have the same results. Thank you for your correction.